# How do I change PATH for RubyMine system-wide?

Tags: path, rubymine

In RubyMine the PATH when running rake tasks, for example, never contains /usr/local/bin, which I need because git is in there.

Is there a rubyMine-wide config of PATH, so I don't have to modify each target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your environment variables in `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` or use the [Environment Variables Preference Pane](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/environmentvariablepreferencepane.html) and they will apply to all of your applications. See [Tip: How to setup Environment variables for RubyMine on Mac OS X](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1160)
 for more information.

Comment: I don't have a ~/.MacOSX directory.

Comment: `~/.MacOSX/` does not exist by default, create it if you need it.

Comment: In the link you provided there was an Environment Variables Preference pane which made it easy, so I edited your question to be more explicit.

Comment: This no longer works in Mountain Lion: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57385/where-are-system-environment-variables-set-in-mountain-lion

Answer (score 2):

RubyMine does not currently have an app-wide `PATH` setting.

In Mountain Lion there [is no longer any reliable way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57385/where-are-system-environment-variables-set-in-mountain-lion) to set the environment like there was using Environment Variables Preference Pane or `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`.

The easiest way to get the same environment in RubyMine as you have in the terminal is to launch RubyMine from Terminal with this:

```
open -a /Applications/RubyMine.app/
```